# Seg faulting on comparison

Tags: c++, gdb, segmentation-fault

I've never seen this before. I'm seg faulting when comparing two integers.

EDIT: Forgot to include the most frustrating part: It runs fine in DDD so I cant debug this.

Here's my gdb session backtracing the seg fault:

```
> Reading symbols from /home/michael/ecs60/hw3/3/huffman...done.
[New LWP 4109]

warning: Can't read pathname for load map: Input/output error.
Core was generated by `./huffman -d'.
Program terminated with signal 11, Segmentation fault.
#0  0x000000000040123a in huffnode::operator< (this=0x1e39010, hn=...)
    at huffnode.h:54
54      if(weight < hn.weight) {
(gdb) bt
#0  0x000000000040123a in huffnode::operator< (this=0x1e39010, hn=...)
    at huffnode.h:54
#1  0x00000000004021f4 in minheap<huffnode>::add (this=0x7fff15de7490, 
    n=...) at minheap.h:65
#2  0x0000000000401cb4 in decompress () at main.cpp:198
#3  0x00000000004012bb in main (argc=2, argv=0x7fff15de75f8)
    at main.cpp:41 <
```

Here's the offending code:

```
bool huffnode::operator<(const huffnode& hn) {
    if(weight < hn.weight) {
            return true;
    } else if(weight == hn.weight) {
            return small < hn.small;
    } else {
            return false;
    }
};
```

Here is the function that calls the offending code:

```
template<class T>
void minheap<T>::add(T n) {
        if(size + 1 > capacity)
                incCapacity();

        heap[size] = n;
        int index = size;
        if(index == 0) return;
        while(heap[index] < heap[(index + 1)/2 -1] && index != 0) {
                swap(index, ((index+1)/2 - 1));
                index = ((index + 1)/2 - 1);
        }
        size++;
};
```

Here's the portion of decompress that calls minheap::add:

```
unsigned int freq[NUM_CHARS];
for(int i = 0; i < NUM_CHARS; i++) {
        in = getNum();
        freq[i] = in;
}

for(int i = 0; i < NUM_CHARS; i++) {
        if(freq[i] > 0) {
                tree.add(huffnode((int)freq[i], (char) i));
        }
}
```

Thank you, everyone! The seg fault is fixed but now half my program was apparently dependant on broken code, so back to DDD.

Comment: Just a thought: You may want to compare `index` with 0 *first*, and check heap entries afterward.  If it's 0, the code's already compared `heap[0]` with `heap[-1]` before checking bounds.  (Probably not the cause of your segfault in this case, but it's still technically UB.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your stack trace, `hn` is `...`, which indicates that it's probably pointing to bad memory (and given that you're getting a seg-fault, it's almost certain it is).  Are you sure that the `huffnode` being passed to the operator overload is valid?  Has it been initialized?

Examining your stacktrace further, `n` in your`minheap<huffnode>::add` function is also invalid, meaning that `add` is being passed an invalid `huffnode`.  `add` looks like it being called from `decompress`, and since `decompress` does not take any arguments, it's likely in there where you are passing an invalid `huffnode` to `add`.

Given that `add` is being passed directly the return value of the `huffnode` constructor, it looks like it won't get an invalid object, so maybe the `...` in the stack trace is misleading.

The next problem I'd examine is your comparison `heap[index] < heap[(index + 1)/1 - 1]`.  Note that if `index` is `0`, then the second operator will be `heap[-1]`, which is invalid.  Can you ensure that `index` will never be `0` or less?

As a side note, I'd like to point out that the entire conditional:

```
heap[index] < heap[(index + 1)/2 - 1] && index != 0
```

will fail even when `index` is equal to `0` because the `<` operator will be evaluated first, causing a seg-fault.  You should either take the `0` check outside of and before the conditional, or as the first condition.

Lastly, if this is the type of bug that only manifests itself outside of a debugger, then `print` statements become your friend (crude, yes, but they get the job done, if you know what to print).  I'd suggest adding prints to `add` at each iteration of your `while` loop, checking what `index` is.  You could also print in the beginning of `add` what the address of `n` is, and see if it looks like uninitialized memory.  Given how you're adding `huffnode`s to your data structure, I'm pretty sure you're problem is out-of-bounds access in your `heap` array.

Comment: Could I be accessing mewhere out of bounds in the array that stores the T variables, but is still on the page?

Comment: @mcnnowak See my updated answer.  The `huffnode` you are passing to `add` is also invalid, so the problem lies wherever you call `add`, likely in `decompress`.  Post that code as well.

Comment: Added check for index == 0 in minheap::add

Comment: @mcnnowak: Your check does not change anything. `index` becomes 0 later, during iterations of the cycle. You have to swap conditions in the cycle header.

Answer (score 0):

It almost certainly has nothing to do with the integers. One of the two things is probably invalid:

1. the `hn&` reference;
2. the `this` pointer.

Print out both, and you'll see which of the two is the culprit.

**edit**: I notice that you've added more code to your question. There's a problem with the following line:

```
while(heap[index] < heap[(index + 1)/2 -1] && index != 0) {
```

Since the arguments to `&&` are checked from left to right, you need to swap the order of operands to avoid out-of-bounds access when `index == 0`:

```
while(index != 0 && heap[index] < heap[(index + 1)/2 -1]) {
```

Comment: I've added a check to make sure that the &hn is not null... I don't see how I can debug this if it runs fine in DDD.

Comment: (gdb) print hn
\n
$4 = (const huffnode &) @0x1e38ff0: <error reading variable>
Does this mean that the hn reference is invalid?

Comment: @mcnnowak: Yes, it's a bad reference.

Comment: I literally have no idea how to fix this. x.x

Comment: @mcnnowak Post the code where you are comparing two `huffnode`s to each other.

Comment: Just interesting:

`this` in frame 1 is a 64 bit pointer while in frame 0 it shows as 32 bit one. Different objects - yes, but different address length ?

Is it GDB stuff ?

Comment: @mcnnowak `&hn` not being null doesn't help if you are accessing memory where there is no `huffnode`.

Comment: @artapet: At a guess, could be heap vs stack, and `gdb` not printing leading zeroes.

Comment: @mcnnowak you should fix the problem pointed out in my answer first, to be sure this is not causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your reference `hn` is invalid (probably `NULL`) hence why you're getting a Segmentation Fault.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your comparison order in cycle condition

```
 while(heap[index] < heap[(index + 1)/2 -1] && index != 0)
```

You should put the `index != 0` comparison *first*

```
 while(index != 0 && heap[index] < heap[(index + 1)/2 -1])
```

In your original variant the first comparison

```
 heap[index] < heap[(index + 1)/2 -1]
```

is executes for `index == 0`, which is equivalent to

```
 heap[index] < heap[-1]
```

Trying to access the non-existing element with index `-1` is what causing the crash.

---

The check

```
if(index == 0) return;
```

that you apparently "added" to solve this issue does not solve anything. It can only catch the situations when `index` is 0 initially. But it does not catch the situations when `index` becomes 0 later, during iterations of the cycle.

Remove this meaningless `if` and, again, swap the comparisons in the cycle header.